# Detecting equivalent expressions

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns

I'm currently working on a Java application where I need to implement a system for building [BPF](http://biot.com/capstats/bpf.html) expressions. I also need to implement mechanism for detecting equivalent BPF expressions.

Building the expression is not too hard. I can build a syntax tree using the [Interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern) design pattern and implement the `toString` for getting the BPF syntax.

However, detecting if two expressions are equivalent is much harder. A simple example would be the following:

```
A: src port 1024 and dst port 1024
B: dst port 1024 and src port 1024
```

In order to detect that A and B are equivalent I probably need to transform each expression into a "normalized" form before comparing them. This would be easy for above example, however, when working with a combination of nested `AND`, `OR` and `NOT` operations it's getting harder.

Does anyone know how I should best approach this problem?

Comment: I think we need a better definition of "equivalent" here.  Is the context important (as in `net xx.xx.xx.xx/24` is equivalent to `net xyz` due to DNS).

Comment: Detect variables and put them in some order without changing the expression. Realize that b-a and a-b is not same.

Comment: @Jim Garrison It should detect if two expressions are syntactically equivalent. It won't do any dns resolving and it will simply consider your two expressions to be different.

Answer (score 6):

One way to compare boolean expressions may be to convert both to the [disjunctive normal form (DNF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form), and compare the DNF. Here, the variables would be Berkeley Packet Filter tokens, and the same token (e.g. `port 80`) appearing anywhere in either of the two expressions would need to be assigned the same variable name.

There is an interesting-looking applet at http://www.izyt.com/BooleanLogic/applet.php - sadly I can't give it a try right now due to Java problems in my browser.

Comment: Converting to DNF could take exponential time

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure detecting equivalent expressions is either an np-hard or np-complete problem, even for boolean-only expressions. Meaning that to do it perfectly, the optimal way is basically to build complete tables of all possible combinations of inputs and the results, then compare the tables.

Maybe BPF expressions are limited in some way that changes that? I don't know, so I'm assuming not.

If your problems are small, that may not be a problem. I do *exactly* that as part of a decision-tree designing algorithm.

Alternatively, don't try to be perfect. Allow some false negatives (cases which are equivalent, but which you won't detect).

A simple approach may be to do a variant of the normal expression-evaluation, but evaluating an alternative representation of the expression rather than the result. Impose an ordering on commutative operators. Apply some obvious simplifications during the evaluation. Replace a rich operator set with a minimal set of primitive operators - e.g. using de-morgans to eliminate OR operators.

This alternative representation forms a canonical representation for all members of a set of equivalent expressions. It should be an equivalence class in the sense that you always find the same canonical form for any member of that set. But that's only the set-theory/abstract-algebra sense of an equivalence class - it doesn't mean that all equivalent expressions are in the same equivalence class.

For efficient dictionary lookups, you can use hashes or comparisons based on that canonical representation.

Comment: Good point with the NP-hardness, but it's worst-case, I think, with the worst case given by http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form , and N being the number of terms, which will hardly exceed 100.

Comment: @thiton - the way I remember it, the disjunctive (or conjunctive) normal form is easily derived from the results (truth) table. If you have any of these three representations, you have a simple translation to the others. The trick is to derive one of these three respresentations to start with - but if your expressions are simple, that's not really a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely go with syntax normalization. That is, like aix suggested, transform the booleans using DNF and reorder the abstract syntax tree such that the lexically smallest arguments are on the left-hand side. Normalize all comparisons to < and <=. Then, two equivalent expressions should have equivalent syntax trees.